# Electron package, generated folder

Tags: javascript, windows, angular, electron, electron-packager

I want to keep my generated windows app (trought angular code) to a specific folder.
I already read the documentation about the command, so I do:

```
ng build --prod --output-path=dist/win/x64 && electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/img/scm/logo.ico --out=dist/win/x64
```

And then, it generates the index.html and content under `dist/win/x64`, but the windows application is generated under `dist/win/x64/app-win32-ia32`.

I want to have the generated app (`dist/win/x64/app-win32-ia32`) into the main path(`dist/win/x64`), because if not, it won't show any apps.
What can I do?

tl;dr: I want to generate ng build and electron-packager on the same path  without being `/dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Really, I don't know how to do it with electron-packager built in functionality, but you can use a basic `mv` command.

```
ng build --prod --output-path=dist/win/x64 && \
electron-packager . app --overwrite --platform=win32 \
--arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/img/scm/logo.ico --out=./tmp && \
mv ./tmp/app-win32-ia32/* ./dist/win/x64 && \
rm -rf ./tmp
```

I would use either gulp or grunt for such tasks.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean... Something inter operating system ideas? Thank you anyways!!

Comment: Using gulp you can create tasks for this kind of things.

Comment: Would've rated it to most powerfull solution if that was a comment. thanks @Ivan